# How do I add multiple items with a for loop in Python to a SQL table?

Tags: python, sql, json

I'm trying to load all the 150 pokemons from the [Poke Api website](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/) in a SQL table with Python. But unfortunately it loads 1 pokemon to the SQL-table. What do I need to add to make it work? I've tried a lot of things already, my latest solution is a for loop, but it doesn't work..

```
import mysql.connector
import json
import requests

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="",
  database="pokemon",
)
cursor = mydb.cursor()

for i in range(1,150):
    url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/'+ str(i)
    r = requests.get(url)
    pokemontable = json.loads(r.text)

pokemonlist = []
for i in pokemontable:
  pokemon = {
  'id': pokemontabel['id'],
  'name': pokemontabel['name'],
  'weight': pokemontabel['weight'],
  'height': pokemontabel['height']
  }

pokemonlist.append(pokemon)

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE pokemon (id INT(22), name VARCHAR(255), weight INT(22), height INT(22))")

sql = sql = "INSERT INTO pokemon " \
      "(id, name, weight, height) " \
      "VALUES (%(id)s, %(name)s, %(weight)s, %(height)s)"

cursor.execute(sql, pokemon)
print('Yes, I have catch'em all!')

mydb.commit()
mydb.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`pokemonlist.append(pokemon)` should intended to be part of the loop, also you don't need to assign it to variable just do:

```
pokemonlist.append({
  'id': pokemontabel['id'],
  'name': pokemontabel['name'],
  'weight': pokemontabel['weight'],
  'height': pokemontabel['height']
})
```

(or use a list comprehension and build that list when you need it in the query).

The `sql = sql` is probably a typo.

You have two options:

1. either loop over your execute for each pokemon:

```
for p in pokemonlist:
   cursor.execute(sql, p)
```

2. Or create a dynamic sql statement where the values part '(%(id)s, %(name)s, %(weight)s, %(height)s)' is repeated len(pokemonlist) times separated by comma and pass in the pokemonlist to the execute:

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO pokemon(id, name, weight, height) VALUES ' + ','.join(['(%(id)s, %(name)s, %(weight)s, %(height)s)'] * len(pokemonlist))
cursor.execute(sql, pokemonlist)
```

I haven't test this, btw, you might need to use positional rather than named parameters.  If you try it, let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

`pokemonlist.append(pokemon)` line should be indented.
Also you should use this:

```py
sql = """INSERT INTO pokemon 
(id, name, weight, height) 
VALUES (%(id)s, %(name)s, %(weight)s, %(height)s)"""
for pokemon in pokemonlist:
    cursor.execute(sql, pokemon)
```